# React v18 causes error without code changes, JSX no longer accepted?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx, primereact, react-18

Since React 18 I have some errors when rendering the application and can't nest any elements as it seems.
For example, I have the following code in my application:

```jsx
return (
        <Card>
            <div className={`flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center`}>
                {props.icon}
                <h2>{props.text}</h2>
            </div>
            <div className={"flex justify-content-center align-items-center"}>
                <Button onClick={() => props.onButtonClick()} className={"w-2"} label={props.buttonText}/>
            </div>
        </Card>


    );
```

This code worked fine up to React 18, now from 18 version I get the following error:
[image]

Likewise, element arrays can no longer be rendered, again, the following code worked fine in React17:

```jsx
  <DataTable metaKeySelection={false} selectionMode={"single"} onSelectionChange={e => {
                                setSelection(e.value)
                            }} selection={selection} stripedRows={true} showGridlines={true} size={"small"}
                                       value={artifacts}>
                                {colModels}
                            </DataTable>
```

And now since React18 the following problem occurs:
[image]

It seems to me that with v18 React expects React Nodes everywhere and JSX as such is no longer accepted.
These errors disappear as soon as I enclose said elements with a React fragment, is this really the only way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Resolved the first issue with downgrading React type definitions. 
`"@types/react": "^17.0.19"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes React 18 did make some changes I am not sure about your second issue but your first issue with card can be fixed like this...

Just add `<>` and `</>` React Fragment as the singlular child.

```xml
<Card>
   <>
            <div className={`flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center`}>
                {props.icon}
                <h2>{props.text}</h2>
            </div>
            <div className={"flex justify-content-center align-items-center"}>
                <Button onClick={() => props.onButtonClick()} className={"w-2"} label={props.buttonText}/>
            </div>
  </>
</Card>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for your quick answer! I just tried it and the second error can also be fixed if i add a react fragment.

Comment: Excellent!  That is great to hear.

Comment: Any idea of why this is happening?